# Agda: std-lib: List: pattern matching with snoc

Tags: agda, agda-stdlib

I wrote a function to get everything but the last element of a `List` from std-lib:

```
open import Data.List

allButLast : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → List A → List A
allButLast []       = []
allButLast (x ∷ []) = []
allButLast (x ∷ xs) = x ∷ allButLast xs
```

For proof purposes, I would like to rewrite this function using `∷ʳ` instead:

```
allButLast2 : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → List A → List A
allButLast2 []        = []
allButLast2 (xs ∷ʳ x) = xs
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Could not parse the left-hand side allButLast2 (xs ∷ʳ x)
Operators used in the grammar:
  v.∷ʳ   (infixl operator, level 5) [_∷ʳ_ (/Users/fss/Dropbox/Documents/projects/Coding/dev/agda/agda-stdlib-1.4/src/Data/Vec/Base.agda:275,1-5)] 
  ∷ʳ (infixl operator, level 6) [_∷ʳ_ (/Users/fss/Dropbox/Documents/projects/Coding/dev/agda/agda-stdlib-1.4/src/Data/List/Base.agda:351,1-5)]
when scope checking the left-hand side allButLast2 (xs ∷ʳ x) in
the definition of allButLast2
```

I don't understand why it can't parse the left hand side of

```
allButLast2 (xs ∷ʳ x) = xs
```

Comment: could it be because snoc is not a constructor for List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `_∷ʳ_` operator is a function, not a constructor or a pattern synonym](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.List.Base.html#9667), so it can't be used in a pattern:

```
infixl 6 _∷ʳ_

_∷ʳ_ : List A → A → List A
xs ∷ʳ x = xs ++ [ x ]
```